# How to transfer files from local to ec2?

Tags: pulumi

What is the Pulumi equivalent of Terraform "file" provisioner?

Specifically, how can one transfer files from the local computer to remote ec2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this PR](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/pull/191/commits/733235b50e8fbe7d7fe76103e09a70b143d9316d#diff-b68d06e748040f9bad58ea4f48bafe89R66) you can just use the scp2 library to transfer the file yourself. It seems you can invoke any node library from Pulumi. It seems obvious in retrospect but wasn't obvious to me.

UPDATE: You're better off using the [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) library. It is better maintained and also handles file transfers.